# How can I dynamically display multiple values in labels?

Tags: vba, visual-studio, excel

I am trying to build an application that searches a string in a specific column of an excel file and if the string is found, display the corresponding column value For Ex: Say I am searching for a string in an excel file column "N", If the string I am searching for is found then display the "E"th Column value of the same row.The thing is that my code is displaying a single value multiple times in multiple labels of second form.

> FORM1

```
 Imports Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
 Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
 Imports System.Globalization
 Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

 Public Class Form1
    Public Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
        Dim xlWorkBook As Excel.Workbook
        Dim xlWorkSheet As Excel.Worksheet
        Dim range As Excel.Range
        Dim Obj As Object
        Dim pass As String

        If OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
            Dim sr As New System.IO.StreamReader(OpenFileDialog1.FileName)
            MessageBox.Show("You have selected" + OpenFileDialog1.FileName)
            'sr.Close()
        End If

        xlApp = New Excel.Application
        xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(OpenFileDialog1.FileName)
        xlWorkSheet = xlWorkBook.Worksheets("sheet1")

        range = xlWorkSheet.UsedRange
        For rCnt = 1 To range.Rows.Count
            For cCnt = 14 To range.Columns.Count
             If xlWorkSheet.Cells(rCnt, cCnt).value = "3" Or  xlWorkSheet.Cells(rCnt, cCnt).value = "4" Or xlWorkSheet.Cells(rCnt, cCnt).value = "5" Or xlWorkSheet.Cells(rCnt, cCnt).value = "6" Or xlWorkSheet.Cells(rCnt, cCnt).value = "7" Or xlWorkSheet.Cells(rCnt, cCnt).value = "8" Or xlWorkSheet.Cells(rCnt, cCnt).value = "9" Or xlWorkSheet.Cells(rCnt, cCnt).value = "10" Then

                    Obj = CType(range.Cells(rCnt, "E"), Excel.Range)
                    'MessageBox.Show(Obj.value)

                    Foo = Obj.value
                    Form2.Show()
                End If
            Next
        Next

        xlWorkBook.Close()
        xlApp.Quit()
        releaseObject(xlApp)
        releaseObject(xlWorkBook)
        releaseObject(xlWorkSheet)
    End Sub

    Private Sub releaseObject(ByVal obj As Object)
        Try
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(obj)
            obj = Nothing
        Catch ex As Exception
            obj = Nothing
        Finally
            GC.Collect()
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

> FORM2

```
Imports System.Linq
Imports System.Drawing

Public Class Form2
    Private Sub Panel1_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles Panel1.Paint
        Dim label As New Label()
        Dim count As Integer = Panel1.Controls.OfType(Of Label)().ToList().Count

        label.Location = New Point(10, (25 * count))
        'label.Size = New Size(40, 20)
        label.Name = "label_" & (count + 1)
        label.Text = Foo '& (count + 1)
        label.AutoSize = True
        Panel1.Controls.Add(label)

        Dim button As New Button()
        button.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(250, 25 * count)
        button.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(60, 20)
        button.Name = "Print" & (count + 1)
        button.Text = "Print" '& (count + 1)
        AddHandler button.Click, AddressOf Button_Click
        Panel1.Controls.Add(button)
        MessageBox.Show(Foo)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        Dim button As Button = TryCast(sender, Button)
        MessageBox.Show(button.Name + " clicked")
    End Sub
End Class
```

> Module

```
Module Module1

    Public Foo As String

End Module
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly then the event handler `Panel1_Paint` is called multiple times for the same excel cell value. So it could simply be solved by checking if label with particulat name is already there, e.g. like this:

```
Private Sub Panel1_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles Panel1.Paint

    For Each c As Control In Panel1.Controls
        If c Is Label Then
            If ((Label) c).Text = Foo Then
                ' Label alredy there, exit sub...
            End If
        End If
    Next
```

Comment: Hi bro.. can you please elaborate including my example? the thing is that I am getting multiple labels of same text. After few repetations the text gets changed.